# Change attribute from a div when window size change

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, width, attr, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I work with jQuery mobile. In this case i want to add the data-role collapsible to a div, when the screen width less than 960px is.

In my example it only works when you load the site. But I want, that it also works when I resize the browser without reload the page.

The change from > 960 px to < 960 px is for example when you rotate a tablet or resize the browser window by hand.

```
$( document ).on( "pagebeforecreate", function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
       $(".medis_collaps").attr("data-role","collapsible")
    }
});
```

**Edit**

.resize() doesn't work , because it seems that I have to reload the page to make data-role="collapsible" working.

Comment: Perhaps [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) would be useful

Comment: create two elements (collapsible / non-collapsible), hide/show them on `orientationchange`.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wt4QH/

Answer (score 0):

use also  **[resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)**

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   if ($(window).width() < 960) {
       $(".medis_collaps").attr("data-role","collapsible")
    }
});
```

Comment: resize doesn't work , because it seems that I have to reload the page to make data-role="collapsible" working.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind resize and load events as following:

```
$(window).on('resize load pagebeforecreate', function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
       $(".medis_collaps").attr("data-role","collapsible")
    }
});
```

In this case there is no necessity to bind same functionality for ever event.

Comment: resize doesn't work , because it seems that I have to reload the page to make data-role="collapsible" working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$( document ).on( "load resize pagebeforecreate", function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
       $(".medis_collaps").attr("data-role","collapsible")
    }
});
```

Comment: resize doesn't work , because it seems that I have to reload the page to make data-role="collapsible" working.